# Java XML Parsing of complex xml file

Tags: java, xml, parsing

I really hope you can help me on this one.... 
I need to get specific data from my xml file but I am stuck at one point and I can't figure out how to proceed...

I want to get from Network: network name; From Codes: the mcc and mnc code; From Settings:name, id, type, parameter name and value;

So this is the structure of my xml file:

```
<country country="Andorra" isoCode="AD">
    <networks>
        <network name="Mobiland" isMNO="true" ranking="10">
            <codes>
                <code mcc="213" mnc="03" />
            </codes>
            <settings>
                <setting alternativeName="Mobiland AD" ref="s1" name="IAP" id="2266" />
                <setting alternativeName="Mobiland MMS AD" ref="s2" name="MMS" id="2265" />
            </settings>
        </network>
    </networks>
    <settings>
        <setting id="s2" type="mmssetting">
            <parameter name="mms-gprs-access-point-name" value="MMS" />
            <parameter name="mms-gprs-name" value="MMS" />
            <parameter name="mms-gprs-proxy" value="192.168.021.050" />
            <parameter name="mms-gprs-proxy-port" value="9201" />
            <parameter name="mms-url" value="http://mms.ad/mmsc" />
        </setting>
        <setting id="s1" type="iapsetting">
            <parameter name="iap-gprs-access-point-name" value="internet" />
            <parameter name="iap-gprs-name" value="Internet" />
            <parameter name="iap-gprs-url" value="http://google.com" />
        </setting>
    </settings>
</country>
```

This is what I have so far...... and I really can't proceed any further... I have a null pointer exception at String content = cNode.getLastChild().getTextContent().trim(); and I am not sure that I am doing it the right way.....

public void ReadXML() throws ParserConfigurationException, SAXException,
            IOException {

```
    // Get the DOM Builder Factory
    DocumentBuilderFactory factory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();

    // Get the DOM Builder
    DocumentBuilder builder = factory.newDocumentBuilder();

    // Load and Parse the XML document
    // document contains the complete XML as a Tree.
    Document document = builder.parse("D:\\test.xml");

    List<Apn> empList = new ArrayList<Apn>();

    // Iterating through the nodes and extracting the data.
    NodeList nodeList = document.getDocumentElement().getChildNodes();

    for (int i = 0; i < nodeList.getLength(); i++) {

        Node node = nodeList.item(i);
        if (node instanceof Element) {
            //Apn apn = new Apn();
            System.out.println(node.getAttributes().getNamedItem("country")
                    .getNodeValue());

            NodeList childNodes = node.getChildNodes();
            for (int j = 0; j < childNodes.getLength(); j++) {
                Node cNode = childNodes.item(j);


                if (cNode instanceof Element) {
                    String content = cNode.getLastChild().getTextContent()
                            .trim();

                    switch (cNode.getNodeName()) {
                    case "networks":
                        System.out.println(content);
                        break;
                    case "setting":
                        System.out.println(content);
                        break;
                    case "codes":
                        System.out.println(content);
                        // emp.location = content;
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }

        }

    }
}
```

Any help will be appericiated !

Thanks!

Comment: maybe the Castor project (an OXM-tool) might be useful for your task: http://castor.codehaus.org/

Comment: You could write a xsd and transform you xml in java object or not?

Comment: Use trang to generate Schema file from your xml. http://peter-on-java.blogspot.in/2012/10/create-xsd-from-xml-using-trang.html Once you have the schema file you can use XMl-java mapping frameworks like jaxb or castor.Once you have the java classes generated you can use these java class to marshall/unmarshall your xml into java objects or vice versa.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I  think the easiest way to deal with a such complexe xml structure is to write a `xsd schema`  and transform your xml into java object by using `JAXB`

Answer (score 2):

Use XPath. For example, to get the values of the `name` attributes of the `network` elements, you can do this:

```
InputStream is = this.getClass().getResourceAsStream("country.xml");
InputSource inputSource = new InputSource(is);

XPath xpath = XPathFactory.newInstance().newXPath();

String expression = "/country/networks/network/@name";
NodeList names = (NodeList) xpath.evaluate(expression, inputSource, XPathConstants.NODESET);
for (int i = 0; i < names.getLength(); i++) {
  System.out.println(names.item(i).getNodeValue());
}
```

Output:

```
Mobiland
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Declarative Stream Mapping (DSM)](https://mfatihercik.github.io/dsm) stream parsing library to easly convert complex xml to java class. DSM has very powerfull mapping structure and scripting support

First of all, you must define mappings between xml data and your class fields in yaml format.

Here are mapping definitions for your XML.

```
result:     
   type: object
   path: /country       
   fields:
       network:          
          type: array
          path: networks/network
          fields:       
             name: 
               xml: 
                 attribute: true                 
             codes:
               type: array
               path: codes/code
               fields:
                 mcc:
                   xml:
                     attribute: true
                 mnc:
                   xml:
                     attribute: true                      
       settings:
          type: array
          path: settings/setting
          fields:       
             id: 
               xml:
                 attribute: true
             type: 
               xml:
                 attribute: true
             parameter:
               type: array
               fields:
                 name:
                   xml:
                     attribute: true
                 value:
                   xml:
                     attribute: true
```

Java Code to parse XML:

```
DSM dsm=new DSMBuilder(new File("path/to/mapping.yaml")).setType(DSMBuilder.TYPE.XML).create();
Object object =  dsm.toObject(xmlFileContent);
dsm.getObjectMapper().writerWithDefaultPrettyPrinter().writeValue(System.out, object)
```

Here is json representaion of output:

```
{
  "network" : [ {
    "name" : "Mobiland",
    "codes" : [ {
      "mcc" : "213",
      "mnc" : "03"
    } ]
  } ],
  "settings" : [ {
    "id" : "s2",
    "type" : "mmssetting",
    "parameter" : [ {
      "name" : "mms-gprs-access-point-name",
      "value" : "MMS"
    }, {
      "name" : "mms-gprs-name",
      "value" : "MMS"
    }, {
      "name" : "mms-gprs-proxy",
      "value" : "192.168.021.050"
    }, {
      "name" : "mms-gprs-proxy-port",
      "value" : "9201"
    }, {
      "name" : "mms-url",
      "value" : "http://mms.ad/mmsc"
    } ]
  }, {
    "id" : "s1",
    "type" : "iapsetting",
    "parameter" : [ {
      "name" : "iap-gprs-access-point-name",
      "value" : "internet"
    }, {
      "name" : "iap-gprs-name",
      "value" : "Internet"
    }, {
      "name" : "iap-gprs-url",
      "value" : "http://google.com"
    } ]
  } ]
}
```